# I face 404 error when I search single single quote from user search box in word press admin backed

Tags: wordpress, search

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBmJk.png)  How to resolved this issue please help me.Other search box is working fine like 
  costume post search box

Comment: It seems you have exclude this `post type` from the search. Check for Custom Post Type you created.

Comment: I have face problem in user.php

Comment: Doesn't happen in my wp in user.php which may therefore mean you have something affecting your install.  Temporarily deactivate all plugins and use a default theme and see if problem goes away.

Comment: @anmari   I already to deactivate plugin but same issue and its fine working in localhost but did not work on server

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear: you disabled ALL plugins AND switched to an unmodified default theme and problem still happened?  This is important.

What I would do next is:  

1) Check if the problem ONLY happens on user.php, OR does it also happen anywhere else you can search:  on wp/wp-admin/edit.php, wp/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page, wp/wp-admin/edit-comments.php  etc
this would indicate general issue with single quotes

2) Look at what are the differences between localhost and server.  Php version? is magic_quotes enabled?  and so on.,

Comment: @anmari  localhost and server are  both  PHP Version 7.0. magic_quotes enabled. but same issue yet

Comment: Yeah you don't really want magic quotes.  My understanding is that in php 7 they should not be there. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php   I'm just trying to think of things that might be impacting.

Comment: @anmari yes you right but how to resolve issue.